# Slash Command won't show up in bot commands list

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have set the right permissions and scope when inviting bot to my server. The commands don't show up in the list. I have waited 24 hours to let it register, same result.
https://ibb.co/HGJYk67

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.command(name="greet", description="greets the user") 
async def greet(ctx):
    await client.tree.sync()
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

@client.command(name="preet", description="preets the user") 
async def preet(ctx):
    await client.tree.sync()
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

client.run('bot token')
```

Comment: You are registering message commands in your example. Here is a basic example of slash commands: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py

Comment: @moinierer3000 thank you so much bro, it works now. kindly put that as answer so i can close this question.